# CSS Grid: grid-column with span, calc() and CSS variable not working in WebKit browsers

Tags: css, css-grid, css-variables

I'm using a simple grid, where the amount of columns can be configured/overwritten via a CSS variable.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-columns, 1), 1fr);
}

// Mixin for tablet media query
@include tablet {
  .grid {
    --grid-columns: 2;
  }
}

// Mixin for tablet media query
@include desktop {
  .grid {
    --grid-columns: 4;
  }
}
```

Above is a simplified example.

I also have a class that can be used on a "cell", to note whether it is full width or two cells wide (span-half).

```css
@include desktop {
  .span {
    &-full {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
    }

    &-half {
      grid-column: span calc(var(--grid-columns) / 2);
      // or grid-column: auto / span calc(var(--grid-columns) / 2);
    }
  }
}
```

I use a .span-half to create a cell that spans half of the column size set by the --grid-columns variable.

However, this calculation does not work in Chrome or Safari. Firefox renders .span-half correctly (eg. a cell that spans 2 columns in desktop). I see no "invalid value property" in Dev Tools.

Here's a Codepen
https://codepen.io/Bregt/pen/oNbWvzx

I have no clue. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you define `--grid-columns` outside the media queries? Media queries are a scope container for custom variables.

Comment: I did not, but it does not seem to solve the issue wheb I add it to the root.

Comment: I might need to see a bit more code then. A working example would be very helpful.

Comment: You're right, here's a Codepen. https://codepen.io/Bregt/pen/oNbWvzx

Comment: Seems to be a bug with `calc` and `grid-column`. Even without vars it doesn't work. Interestingly enough though this works `grid-column: span calc(2);` while this does not work `grid-column: span calc(4 / 2);`

Answer (score 6):

Found this on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

> **Note:** The Chrome browser currently won’t accept some values returned by calc() when an integer is expected. This includes any division, even if it results in an integer.

Here are a few tests I ran in Chrome in connection with `grid-column`:

`grid-column: calc(4 / 2);` = Invalid property value

`grid-column: calc(1 * 2);` = Works

`grid-column: calc(4 * 0.5);` = Invalid property value

`grid-column: calc(1 + 1.5);` = Invalid property value

`grid-column: calc(1 + 2);` = Works

`grid-column: calc(1 - 2);` = Works

Conclusion: Division doesn't work with `grid-column` (possibly also rows). Multiplication, addition and subtraction works as long as no floating point numbers are used. This also applies to other css properties such as `z-index` that require an integer as a value without any units.

Properties like `line-height` that accept floating point numbers don't have this issue.

Comment: Yep, same with rows.

Comment: Note this is [no longer the case as of Chrome 97](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5656451751084032).

Answer (score 2):

The media queries aren't the problem you're asking about, but they contribute tot he issue.

Basically you're scoping the variables when you wrap them in a class so you can't do any calculations on them. (`.grid {--grid-columns: 4}`) Instead. You should simply set a base in the root and then change the base in media queries.

```
:root {
 --grid-columns: 4;
}

@media (args) {
  :root {
     --grid-columns: 8;
  }
}
```

This changes all of the variables throughout your code. So you don't have to mess with anything other than variables.

As for the rest, it seems to be an issue with `calc()` that has nothing to do with custom properties.

this works:

```
grid-column: span 2;
```

this does not (webkit)

```
grid-column: span calc(4 / 2);
```

I believe it has something to do with calc not liking unitless values but I can't find that in any official documentation or any mention of this in the Chromium bugs.

**edit:** This seems to be a Chromium bug since Chrome, Edge, Safari all experience it. Also `calc()` works with +, -, * as noted by Aedan in the comments. I added a [Chromium bug for this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1097984). If this is something you would use, feel free to star the bug to help the team understand that.

And here's a Codepen with the [full example](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/mdVmdvg).

Comment: Span is unitless, I don't think i can get around that.

Comment: As for the media queries and :root. You are right, I should not have written the selector again indeed. Probably part of a leftover of trying to find out what was wrong. Thx.

Comment: I agree that you can't get around the unitless part. I think its a bug with what calc() actually outputs (possibly invalid). I'm trying to determine if its a bug in the `grid` implementation or the `calc` implementation.

Comment: I ran some tests as well. It seems to be related to the division operator only inside of `calc` in connection with `grid-column`. Multiplication works fine. This gave me the idea to just use `calc(4 * 0.5)` but there seems to be a separate bug in webkit that doesn't allow for floating-point numbers to be used in `calc` & `grid-column`. floating-point numbers in `calc` outside `grid-column` works fine. Oh man... what a day.

Comment: @Aedan good to know. The multiplying by a decimal has to do with how numbers vs integers are evaluated in `calc()`. I can't find anything that says FF is wrong and Chrome is right so I filed a [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1097984). I'll amend it to show division only. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Bryce Howitson I actually just found some official infos from Mozilla on `calc` about this Chrome bug. I posted a more in-depth answer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It seems like an error in implementation, not a bug :-) especially because it now affects Chrome, MS Edge & Safari. That's a pretty big market share of devices. Guess my bug will either tell me they don't care or will validate the need to fix it.

Comment: Wow, thanks all. Interesting to follow this process.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your issue several ways. It's a `calc` bug. Using `var` is absolutely OK. But event if I put `calc` in a separate `var` - this will not work neither.

**UPDATED**

I just want to demonstrate the simple JavaScript solution. You should't edit the code anyway, you can just work with CSS as usual. This JS only gets `--grid-columns` and send back `--grid-span` back. Basically this is what `calc()` do in CSS, but much more stable.

```js
setDimensions(); 
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
 setDimensions(); 
});
function setDimensions(){
  let gridColumns = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--grid-columns');
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--grid-span', gridColumns / 2);
}
```

```css
:root {
    --grid-columns: 1;    
  }
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-columns, 1), 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px 10px
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  :root {
    --grid-columns: 4;
  }
}

.span-full {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.span-half {
  grid-column: span var(--grid-span);
}

.cell {
  background: #77dd77;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell span-full">full</div>
  <div class="cell span-half">half</div>
  <div class="cell span-half">half</div>
  <div class="cell span-half">half</div>
  <div class="cell">single</div>
  <div class="cell">single</div>
  <div class="cell">single</div>
  <div class="cell">single</div>
  <div class="cell span-half">half</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to log this somewhere then? Because my example is simplified. I want rhe span-half to be calculatee only once. I have grids with 8 columns for example.

Comment: I think you should do calculations on JS. If you are ok with using JS - I can write simple script.

Comment: JS is really not an option

Comment: Updated an answer with JS, just look, you can just take it and use, without editing. Only thing is need for it's work - `--grid-columns` in CSS

Comment: Why don't you try JS? It is so simple and works 100% stable and multibrowser.

Comment: In my situation, I have no access to the JavaScript.